# Is there a cleaner way to register Qt custom events?

Tags: c++, qt, macros, qevent

I need to create several custom event classes for a Qt application.

Right now, it looks like I will need to implement the following event type registration code for each event class:

```
class MyEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    MyEvent() : QEvent(registeredType())
    {
    }

    static QEvent::Type eventType;

private:
    static QEvent::Type registeredType();
}

QEvent::Type MyEvent::eventType = QEvent::None;

QEvent::Type MyEvent::registeredType()
{
    if (eventType == QEvent::None)
    {
        int generatedType = QEvent::registerEventType();
        eventType = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(generatedType);
    }
    return eventType;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can simplify this, or at least hide it with a macro?

Comment: You can also have a look at [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8232397/5253471). It worked well for me.

Comment: @Francois Yes, the answer you have linked to provides a more elegant solution than this plus the fact that in general event types are defined as constants in order to prevent overriding an event out of nowhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what templates are for. They can be used with constant integral parameters, which need to be known at compile time too:

```
enum EventNames { UpdateEvent,... }

template<EventNames E>
class MyEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    MyEvent() : QEvent(registeredType())
    {
    }

    static QEvent::Type eventType;

private:
    static QEvent::Type registeredType();
}
```

The common code lokes like this:

```
template<EventNames E>
QEvent::Type MyEvent<E>::registeredType()
{
    if (eventType == QEvent::None)
    {
        int generatedType = QEvent::registerEventType();
        eventType = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(generatedType);
    }
    return eventType;
}
```

Static initialization (beware!) looks like this:

```
QEvent::Type MyEvent<UpdateEvent>::eventType = QEvent::None;
```

The code specific for each event type can be implemented as template specialization then.

Comment: Great! If I create additional event classes, does that mean I will need to change the `enum`?

Comment: Yes. You will also need a initialize each template-static, but if you create more than one event object from a given type, they will share the static as usual

Comment: You can also just initialize the template-static with a template: `template<EventNames E> QEvent::Type MyEvent<E>::eventType = QEvent::None;`, then you don't need to update the initialization for every event type. This is about the only place where you can use templates on non-class non-function types.