# Why does Qt reimplement RTTI in qobject_cast, event type, etc?

Tags: qt, metaobject

Why does Qt bother reimplementing what amounts to a custom RTTI system and a their own `dynamic_cast` in the `QObject` hierarchy, in `QEvent`, etc?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, only a few class hierarchies in Qt actually need RTTI. When you generate embedded code you can save a whole bunch of code space by not emitting RTTI information. When building Qt and suitably written projects that use it, you can turn off RTTI in the compiler. You can't use `dynamic_cast` anymore, thus `QObject` hierarchy has its own `qobject_cast`, and `QEvent` uses explicit integer type tags.

A custom RTTI system for `QObject` hierarchy also allows dynamic creation of types from their metadata, as well of the metadata of new types that the compiler was unaware of. That's why QML can work, for example. In Qt 5, this functionality is offered by the private [`QMetaObjectBuilder`](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobjectbuilder_p.h.html). The [legacy way of creating dynamic signals and slots](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq16-dynamicqobject.html) wasn't compatible with standard `QObject::connect`.

Historically, with some compilers `dynamic_cast` failed across shared library boundaries.